# how to add a UI Search bar in a stack flutter

Tags: flutter

how can I add my search bar in a different stack in my code? without creating a widget. here's my home. dart file. as you can see I have added a search bar in a different widget at the end of the code. please help me to add this same code in a stack. if it is not possible suggest me another way to do this.

> home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();}

class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage>{
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffEDEFF4),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 20, right: 20),//padding for search bar 
        child: ListView (
          children: [
            buildSearchInput(), //searchbar 
            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 45, 10, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),
                        height: 137,
                        width: 327,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                                "Banana",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily:'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                        )
                ),

                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/banana.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),


            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 45, 10, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),
                        height: 137,
                        width: 327,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                                "Tangerine",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily:'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                ),

                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/orange.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),


            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 45, 10, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),
                        height: 137,
                        width: 327,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                                "Kiwi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily:'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                ),

                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/kiwi.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),





          ],

        ),
      ),
      );

  }

//search bar 
  Widget buildSearchInput() => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 30,
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it by wrapping it inside Positioned() widget, specifying top, left [and right] padding values.

For it to be visible, insert it as the last item in stack, that way it will be the topmost one on Z axis.

By specifying top,left [and right] values close to **0**, it will appear on top and above all other widgets in the stack.